# Keil Arm Compiler: Is there a way to hook in the same function for two interrupts without modifying the Interrupt Vector Table?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, interrupt-handling, keil

In an embedded project, I need to handle two different external interrupts with the same IRQ handler. 
I don't want to change the interrupt vector table entries in the startup assembly directly, so that I have to stick with the predefined function names for the IRQ-handler routines (EXTI9_5_IRQHandler and EXTI15_10_IRQHandler).

For both interrupts, I need the exact same code to handle the interrupt.

Of course, I can program this like this:

```
void realIRQHandler (void)
{
    //do some magic interrupt handling here
    return;
}

void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void)
{
    realIRQHandler();   //calls the real IRQ handler function
}

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void)
{
    realIRQHandler();   //calls the real IRQ handler function
}
```

This will eventually do what I want, but it will have an ordinary function call with the overhead of pushing and restoring the registers to the stack in each interrupt invocation.

Is there a way to replace those function calls in `EXTI9_5_IRQHandler` and `EXTI15_10_IRQHandler`somehow and replace it with some unconditional branch or jump?

What would be needed at the end of `realIRQHandler` when returning/exiting?

Thanks!
Regards,
Felix

Comment: I don't think there should be [any meaningful overhead here](https://godbolt.org/z/P4EyVa).

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to change the interrupt vector table entries in the startup assembly directly

This is the problem. The *only* correct solution to the table is to modify the vector table. Therefore, the vector table shouldn't be defined in some startup file but in a file of its own. Either a linker script or a .c file (array of function pointers).

If you can't modify the vector table you can't do microcontroller programming on your tool chain. So if your compiler/linker can't provide an easy way to do this, you will have to customize the start-up code.

Comment: It's the Keil v5 toolchain and this one has the vector table defined in its start up. Believe me, I didn't opt for chosing that toolchain. It's my customer who told me whats good for me. And it's my customer who doesn't want me to change the table directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can hint the compiler to inline `realIRQHandler`.

Otherwise you don't have anything on the stack in `EXTI9_5_IRQHandler` or `EXTI15_10_IRQHandler`, and `realIRQHandler` doesn't take any parameter nor returns anything. The only thing you'll push on the stack is the frame pointer.

Or, you can use `goto`.

Edit : depending on the optimisation level you chose, the compiler might just do a simple Branch Exchange, which is more or less a `goto`.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not consistent: it seems like your interrupt handling duration is very critical (since you want to avoid function calls overhead), but at the same time you want to use the same function for two interrupts. Which means this function will need to do the "extra work" of checking whether the interrupt EXTI9_5 or ETXI15_10 was asserted. Wouldn't it be more efficient to have two different functions, one for each interrupt line ? Or at least pass the interrupt number as a  parameter to `realIRQHandler` ?

Comment: The application of my idea is: There are two interrupts (data ready lines) which are supposed to get low at the _same_ time. However, one of them will definitely be the first one, but I don't know which on this will be. And so I thought of using the IRQ handler to react on either one and start a busy wait for the other one. If this times out, they are not synchronous and the system goes into error.
The total execution time is not that crucial in fact. 
The idea to put it into one function is more due to code maintenance and "poshness" and that I want to know how this would work.

Comment: passing the IRQ number as parameter is a very good idea. I'll consider this.

Comment: @opt12 be careful because it looks like realIRQHandler  will be reentrant (if a handler is interrupted by the other interrupt, which may happen depending on the interrupt priorities or trigger order). Also busy waiting in a IRQ handler is not always the best solution since it might lead to deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by disassembling the compiled code, but the comment of @Groo is completely correct.

> I don't think there should be [any meaningful overhead here](https://godbolt.org/z/P4EyVa)

If your function has same prototype as the interrupt handler (aka `void realIRQHandler(void)`) the compiler will not do any overhead.